# webconfig rewrite rule to add www prefix

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add the rule to make sure all three hostnames of my website are prefixed with www.

I want all the below websites to be prefixed with www.

These are my websites,

1. remserv.com.au
2. remservlease.com.au
3. remservsalarypackage.com.au

I want it to be redirected to,

1. www.remserv.com.au
2. www.remservlease.com.au
3. www.remservsalarypackage.com.au

The rule i have added. Only my third URL is getting redirected (remservsalarypackage.com.au)

```
<rule name="add-www-prefix" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^remserv(.*).com.au$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting C:0 in the "action type" in this way:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

Maybe if that is not working try to add the "\" in the conditions to see the "." :

```
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^remserv(.*)\.com\.au$" />
  </conditions>
```

The R:x is the back-reference for the "rule"; The C:x is the back-reference for the "conditions"